# Rails form builder - how to improve performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, performance, forms

I have a page that has several forms and the load time of the form and fields seems like it is way slower than it should be.

My form looks something like this

```
-@leaders = Leader.select("id, full_name")
-@managers = Leader.select("id, full_name")

=form_for organization, remote: true do |f|
  =f.fields_for :projects, [project] do |project_fields|
    Status:
    =project_fields.collection_select :status_id, Status.all, :id, :title

    Current Manager
    =project_fields.fields_for :project_managers, [pm] do |project_manager_fields|
      -# 50+ entries          
      =project_manager_fields.collection_select :manager_id, @managers, :id, :full_name

    Current Lead
    =project_fields.fields_for :project_leads, [pl]  do |project_lead_fields|
      -# 50+ entries
      =project_lead_fields.collection_select :lead_id, @leaders, :id, :full_name
```

This is just a contrived example.  I have everything preloaded so fields_for doesn't hit the database.  This made a huge difference but its still too slow.   I also tried caching the content of each for which made the speed acceptable but I don't think caching is the intended solution for this.

Is there anything else I can do to get this to render faster?

ruby 1.9.2 or 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.6, sqlserver adapter (everything is even slower with mysql), Ubuntu 10.04 VM (hosted in windows 2k3), 4gb, 3ghz xeon cpu

This is slow in development and production on mongrel/passenger, other pages load acceptably fast.

Comment: Is the problem only for loading forms? or you have slow page load in general? What server are you using? webrick?

Comment: Other pages are fine, updated op

Comment: add more information about your environment setup, also database used, adapters, etc

Comment: have you tried eager loading of the associations of `organization` (`projects` => `status`, `manager`, `leader`) see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: are you using NAT under the VM guest?

Comment: Bridged network in vmware.

Comment: There are 5-20 forms on the page, each one is a table row, essentially.  The user usually only edits one or two at a time, but they need to see all of them as an overview.

Comment: Are you using turbolinks gem?

Comment: I'm not using turblinks.  In my actually application the logger shows all the data being preloaded, nothing is loaded from the database during the form select

Answer (score 2):

Recently, while optimizing a Rails app for performance, I found that some of the Rails form helpers are surprisingly slow. I was able to multiply rendering speed for several heavily used pages by replacing form helper calls with raw string interpolation.

To get the HTML generated by a helper, open up the page in Chrome, press F12 to open the Dev Tools, go into Elements, right click on the  element, and choose "Copy HTML". Then copy the raw HTML into your template, and use `#{}` string interpolation as necessary to insert values in the right places. For the authenticity token `<input>`, use `value="#{form_authenticity_token}"`.

This is ugly, some might even say hideous, but it's also FAST. By applying this change in some critical places, together with optimization of DB indexes and a few other changes, I was able to make the above-mentioned app handle 3.6x as much load on the same server!

Answer (score 0):

What about only using the necessary fields of the model?

```
=form_for organization, remote: true do |f|
  =f.fields_for :projects, [project] do |project_fields|
    Status:
    =project_fields.collection_select :status_id, Status.find(:all,:select=>'id,title'), :id, :title

    Current Manager
    =project_fields.fields_for :project_managers, [pm] do |project_manager_fields|
      -# 50+ entries          
      =project_manager_fields.collection_select :manager_id, Manager.find(:all,:select=>'id,full_name'), :id, :full_name

    Current Lead
    =project_fields.fields_for :project_leads, [pl]  do |project_lead_fields|
      -# 50+ entries
      =project_lead_fields.collection_select :lead_id, Leader.find(:all,:select=>'id,full_name'), :id, :full_name
```

Comment: I actually do that, also helped.

Comment: In your post Status is still loading all fields.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing there are so many forms, I guess the page itself would be too long to fit a screen. The user definitely can't handle so much information in short time.

So, if possible, why not load the necessary divs only at first? Then you can use toggle to display form on need by Ajax.

Comment: I could do that, still seems like there should be a better way.